# Specical formatting of textarea output to page creating a link with some data

Tags: javascript, mysql, formatting, string-formatting, code-formatting

I am not sure if this is possible.  I have searched for a couple of days with no luck. I would like to take information from a TEXT field of my database and create a list with the actors name being a link.

For example....

As it is now, the TEXT field outputs this:

> Bill Murray - Peter Venkman
>
> Dan Aykroyd - Ray Stantz
>
> Harold Ramis - Egon Spengler
>
> Sigourney Weaver - Dana Barrett
>
> Ernie Hudson - Winston Zeddemore

What I would like to do is have the Actor's Name a link...  So, Bill Murray would be a link, Dan Aykroyd would be a link and so on. I would like the actors name to be passed as a variable for a search.

Is this possible?

Thanks

**EDIT - 12/8/2017**

I found a way to somewhat do this....

```
$data = $acast;
list($actor, $char) = explode("-", $data);
$actorlink = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $actor);
echo '<a href=index.php?actor='.$actorlink.'>'.$actor.'</a> - '.$char.'<br>';
```

This will produce the 1st line perfect. and start the 2nd line with just the actors name, no link and no character.  Like so.

> Main Cast:
>
> [Mary Elizabeth Winstead](http://#) - Michelle
>
> John Goodman

I think a foreach statement is needed but I cannot figure out how to incorporate it with the results. Or expand the list results to beyond 1.  I have 5 cast members per movie. I have tried this...

```
list($actor, $char) = explode("-", $data, 2);
```

That will list all 5 actors but only the 1st has a link. Like this....

> Main Cast:
>
> [Mary Elizabeth Winstead](http://link.two) - Michelle
>
> John Goodman - Howard
>
> John Gallagher Jr. - Emmett
>
> Bradley Cooper - Ben
>
> Douglas M. Griffin - Driver

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: In a text field? Nope, it's not possible. Fields in HTML doesn't support formatting. You could, however, use [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content).

Comment: Yes, you can. Take actors and their link in Object{key:value} pair. Use regex replacement-find actors and then replace with link tag.

Comment: I am very new to PHP.... I am not sure how to use Object{key:value}.  This thing I am working on is my attempt to learn php.  I basically know MySQL calls and how to display data on a page with php.  I need to learn to set functions, globals, variables etc.... What little PHP I do know is for older versions... 7+ is a bit different LOL.  If you can explain in greater detail or give an example that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT!!  1st off - Sorry.... I just noticed that this was Javascript, I thought I was posting under PHP. Ooops....

That said... If anyone needs a PHP solution to my problem, I figured it out.

```
<?php
                //Seperate data into rows.
                $c_row = list($all) = explode("\n", $row['Cast']);
                //Seperate and list the values from the row.
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach ($c_row as $cast) {
                    list($actor, $char) = preg_split("/[-]/", $cast);
                    if ($char == "") {
                        $char = "Not Added Yet.";
                    }
                    echo "<li><a style='color: #e33e32; font-size: 14px;' href='index.php?actor=" . $actor . "'data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='auto' title=' List all " . $actor . " movies. '>" . $actor . "</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $char . " </li>";
                }
                echo '</ul>';
                ?>
```

The above code will give me the desired results.  You can see them in action [here](http://movieguide.applebitemedia.com/index.php?pid=minfo&Movie_Id=1079).  Also notice that I used a similar process to separate out directors when there are more than one.